# boost::scoped_lock unlock

Tags: c++, boost

Could I unlock the mutex before out of the scope of scoped_lock? How could I do that?

```
{boost::mutex::scoped_lock  lock(mutex);

if(conditionaA)
{
   if(conditionB)
   {
    //could I unlock here as I don't want to hold the lock too long.
    //perform calculation
   }

}
else
{

}

}//lock scope
```

Thanks.

Comment: Rate down for not reading the documentation, I would double rate down because google would show the solution as the first result for "scoped_lock unlock", triple rate down because the unlock method is called unlock.

Comment: Pure laziness asking this question on SO.  -1.

Answer (score 16):

Yes.

Use the `unlock()` method.

```
{boost::mutex::scoped_lock  lock(mutex);

if(conditionaA)
{
   if(conditionB)
   {
    //could I unlock here as I don't want to hold the lock too long.
    lock.unlock(); // <--
   }

   //perform calculation

}
else
{

}

}//lock scope
```

Answer (score 6):

Yes; just use the .unlock() member function.

Answer (score 2):

`boost::mutex::scoped_lock` is the same as `boost::unique_lock<mutex>` and you can unlock them. It must be locked by your thread to do this or you get an exception.

The destructor of unique_lock ensures that the mutex is unlocked at destruction time, and the purpose of using the lock object is thus to ensure this (exception safety) if an exception is thrown at any time the lock is held.